# How to retrieve data from firebase database in android

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, picasso

Retrieving images from Firebase does not work? Hi I am working on upload and retrieve images from Firebase. I have successfully done the uploading part, but while doing for the retrieving one. I have came across a problem where i am unable to fetch image from Firebase. I am using Picasso version: 2.5.2

**QuoteList.java**

```
public class QuoteList extends AppCompatActivity {

    private StorageReference storageRef;

  private   RecyclerView  mRecyclerView;
  private DatabaseReference mReference;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quote_list);

    final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.quotes_list);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    mReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Quotes");
}


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Quote, QuoteViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter =
            new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Quote, QuoteViewHolder>(
                    Quote.class,
                    R.layout.quote_row,
                    QuoteViewHolder.class,
                    mReference
            ) {

                @Override
                protected void populateViewHolder(QuoteViewHolder viewHolder , Quote model , int position) {

                        viewHolder.setQuotes(model.getQuotes());
                        viewHolder.setQuoteAuthor(model.getQuote_Author());
                        viewHolder.setImage(getApplicationContext(),model.getImages());


                }
            };

    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

}

public class QuoteViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    View mView;

    public QuoteViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mView = itemView;
    }

    public void setQuotes(String Quote){
        TextView post_quote = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_quote);
        post_quote.setText(Quote);
    }

    public void setQuoteAuthor(String QuoteAuthor){
        TextView post_quoteAuthor = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_author);
        post_quoteAuthor.setText(QuoteAuthor);
    }

    public void setImage(Context ctx, String image){
        ImageView post_image = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_image);
        Picasso.with(ctx).load(image).into(post_image);

    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

}

For reference i have used a Youtube [Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yx8lRrclCYo&index=21&list=PLGCjwl1RrtcTXrWuRTa59RyRmQ4OedWrt).

Comment: This demo is, how to fetch firebase data in RecycleView? try this, Hope It's helpful for you. Thank You.  https://github.com/chetanmahajan850/RecycleviewDemo

Comment: What does `model.getImages()` return? Please responde with @.

Comment: @alex it will reference to a another class called Quote.java where i used gettter setter and constructor.

Comment: @itzPrateek It is or it is not returning the desired url?

Comment: no it wasn't @AlexMamo

Comment: What is it returning?